# How to execute all Tasks in the List<Task> regardless of exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have code as shown below.  Into each Task function I pass a reference to an object where any exceptions that occur within the task can be logged.  What I want is for every task in my List to execute regardless of whether or not an exception has occurred (because I am already logging the exception in the function.)  So what I want is for all Tasks in the lobj_CustomFieldsTasks list of tasks to execute regardless of any of them encountering an exception.  Any suggestions?

NOTE: This code cannot be copied and work - it is a summary of what I am trying to do.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LANrevTargetBL
{
public class myEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public eAPIFunction CompletedProcessName { get; set; }
    public List<Exception> AsyncErrors { get; set; }
}


/// <summary>
/// Class for Devices.  Used for Applying and Removing profiles 
/// </summary>
public class DevicesVM
{

    private async Task LoadCustomFieldsAndServerProfiles(myEventArgs pobj_myEventArgs)
    {
        List<Task> lobj_CustomFieldsTasks;
        lobj_CustomFieldsTasks = new List<Task>();

        // The iobj_AllDevices list is defined as a List<Device> where Device is a custom data class I have
        foreach (Device lobj_Device in iobj_AllDevices)
        {
            lobj_CustomFieldsTasks.Add(MakeCustomFieldCall(lobj_Device.ID, pobj_myEventArgs));
        }

        try
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(lobj_CustomFieldsTasks);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            pobj_myEventArgs.AsyncErrors.Add(ex);
        }
    }

    private async Task MakeCustomFieldCall(int pi_DeviceID, myEventArgs pobj_myEventArgs1)
    {
        string ls_WorkRoomList;
        Device lobj_Device;
        APICallHelper lobj_APICallHelper;
        CustomFieldMetaData.RootObject lobj_CustomFieldResult;

        try
        {

            lobj_APICallHelper = new APICallHelper();

            var lobj_ReturnTask = await lobj_APICallHelper.MakeAPICall(eAPIFunction.eCustomFields, "", pi_DeviceID.ToString());

            if (lobj_ReturnTask.Exceptions == null)
            {
                if (iobj_AllDevices != null)
                {
                    lobj_Device = (from lobj_FoundItem in iobj_AllDevices
                                   where lobj_FoundItem.ID == pi_DeviceID
                                   select lobj_FoundItem).ElementAt(0);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Exception lobj_Exception in lobj_ReturnTask.Exceptions)
                {
                    pobj_myEventArgs1.AsyncErrors.Add(lobj_Exception);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            pobj_myEventArgs1.AsyncErrors.Add(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are all correct.  The WhenAll will do exactly what I wanted.  My problem was that an exception actually being thrown in my exception handlers.  My AsyncErrors object was actually null and thus it looked like the WhenAll was not handling exceptions as desired.  Thank you to everybody for their input.

Answer (score 2):

Then [`WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh160384(v=vs.110).aspx) function basically already does what you want to do. It runs all the tasks to completion. In case one or multiple of the tasks faulted with a exception, the resulting `Task` will also enter the faulted state with a [`AggregateException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.aggregateexception(v=vs.110).aspx). This exception is thrown by `await` once all tasks are done. You are able to fetch the real exceptions that happened in your tasks in the `InnerExceptions` property. So it basically already collects the exceptions in the way you are trying to do.

So all in all: You do not need to change anything, except the recording of the exceptions that you may need to unpack.

Answer (score 1):

Use plain `foreach` instead of `Task.WhenAll`

```
foreach (var task in lobj_CustomFieldsTasks)
{
    try { await task; }
    catch (Exception ex) { pobj_myEventArgs.AsyncErrors.Add(ex); }
}
```

The above works because you already created (started) all the tasks in advance. `Task.WhenAll` is just a convenient way of `await`ing all the task to complete, with additional exception/cancellation logic that you don't want. In contrast, `Task.WhenAny` cannot be replaced so easily, but there is no need for that because it doesn't throw exceptions.

For more details, see [await (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx).

Comment: That will not take advantage of the parallel processing that the WhenAll achieves.

Comment: There is no parallel processing achieved by `WhenAll`. Once you start all the tasks (and you did in the first loop), they already run in parallel regardless of if `WhenAny`, `WhenAll` or `await` order is used.

Answer (score 0):

No need to try/catch anything. WaitAll runs all tasks, and any exceptions are aggregated for you. Have a look at the example at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx.

In the example, all tasks are executed, and when they are finished an AggregateException is thrown. If you're not interested in these aggregated exceptions, you can of course ignore this exception.